# How to run python loop until correct input string is entered

Tags: python, loops, while-loop, user-input

I have to write a code that will execute the below while loop only if the user enters the term "Cyril".

I am a real newbie, and I was only able to come up with the below solution which would force the user to restart the program until they enter the correct input, but I would like it to keep asking the user for input until they input the correct answer. Could anybody perhaps assist? I know I would probably kick myself once I realise there's a simple solution.

```
number_list = []
attempts = 0
name = False
number = 0

name_question = input("You are the President of RSA, what is your name?: ")
if name_question == "Cyril":
    name = True
else:
    print("\nThat is incorrect, please restart the program and try again.\n")  

if name:
    number = int(input("Correct! Please enter any number between -1 and 10: "))
    while number > -1:
        number_list.append(number)
        number = int(input("\nThank you. Please enter another number between -1 and 10: "))
    if number > 10:
        print("\nYou have entered a number outside of the range, please try again.\n")
        number = int(input("Please enter a number between -1 and 10: "))
    elif number < -1:
        print("\nYou have entered a number outside of the range, please try again. \n")
        number = int(input("Please enter a number between -1 and 10: "))
    elif number == -1:
        average_number = sum(number_list) / len(number_list)
        print("\nThe average number you have entered is:", round(average_number, 0))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change beginning of code to:

```
while True:
    name_question = input("You are the President of RSA, what is your name?: ")
    if name_question == "Cyril":
        name = True
        break
    else:
        print("\nThat is incorrect, please try again.\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this even if I don't understand if your question is easy or if I am an idiot:

```
name_question = input("You are the President of RSA, what is your name?: ")
while name_question != "Cyril":
    name_question = input("You are the President of RSA, what is your name?: ")
...
```